# Multiple nested SELECT DISTINCTstatments using INNER JOIN on the same table

Tags: php, sql, join, distinct

I have been trying to write a query to select only the most recent of every 'Item No_' in the table by posting date and ignoring the rest of the rows. I have been getting various errors. The last of which is an annoyance as I cannot see the error at this point. Here is a snippet of the query:

```
SELECT ri.* 
FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] ri 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT DISTINCT [Item No_], MAX([Posting Date]) AS maxDate 
    FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] 
    WHERE maxDate <= CONVERT(datetime, '2014-01-17 02:33:16.939') 
    GROUP BY maxDate, [Item No_]] 
  ) itDat 
  ON ri.[Item No_] = itDat.[Item No_] 
WHERE ri.[Quantity] > 0 
ORDER BY ri.[Location Code] DESC, ri.[Item No_] ASC, ri.[Posting Date] DESC;
```

With the help of Peter G and rs, I came to a solution.

```
SELECT E.*
FROM [Rigid Industries\$Item Ledger Entry] E
WHERE [Posting Date] = 
    (SELECT MAX(x.[Posting Date])
    FROM [Rigid Industries\$Item Ledger Entry] x 
    WHERE x.[Item No_] = E.[Item No_] 
    AND x.[Posting Date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '$dateYo')
    ) AND
    [Entry No_] = 
    (SELECT MAX(y.[Entry No_])
    FROM [Rigid Industries\$Item Ledger Entry] y
    WHERE y.[Item No_] = E.[Item No_] 
    )
AND E.[Quantity] > 0 
ORDER BY E.[Location Code] DESC, E.[Item No_] ASC, E.[Posting Date] DESC;
```

Comment: SELECT E.*
  FROM [Rigid Industries\$Item Ledger Entry] E
  WHERE [Posting Date] = 
   (SELECT MAX(x.[Posting Date])
            FROM [Rigid Industries\$Item Ledger Entry] x 
            WHERE x.[Item No_] = E.[Item No_] 
   AND x.[Posting Date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '$dateYo')
   ) AND
   [Entry No_] = 
   (SELECT MAX(y.[Entry No_])
            FROM [Rigid Industries\$Item Ledger Entry] y
            WHERE y.[Item No_] = E.[Item No_] 
   )
  AND E.[Quantity] > 0 
  ORDER BY E.[Location Code] DESC, E.[Item No_] ASC, E.[Posting Date] DESC;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can rewrite your query to this

```
SELECT E.*
    FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] E
    WHERE [Posting Date] = (SELECT MAX(x.[Posting Date]) FROM 
                            FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] x  
                            WHERE x.[Item No_] = E.[Item No_] AND 
                x.[Posting Date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2014-01-17 02:33:16.939'))
AND E.[Quantity] > 0 
ORDER BY E.[Location Code] DESC, E.[Item No_] ASC, E.[Posting Date] DESC;
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. This makes more sense that what I was trying to do. I took this query and combined it with the suggestion of Peter G.

Comment: You can still end up with two rows for a single item number using this query.  I would suggest changing the where clause to something more like this:  WHERE [Entry No_] = (SELECT TOP 1 [Entry No_] 
                            FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] x  
                            WHERE x.[Item No_] = E.[Item No_] AND 
                x.[Posting Date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2014-01-17 02:33:16.939')
  ORDER BY x.[Posting Date] DESC, [Entry No_] DESC)

Answer (score 0):

Your have a couple of problems.  One syntax error is that the inner query is aggregating by `maxdate`, and then there are others.  That is unnecessary.  The logical problem is that you need to use the date in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT ri.* 
FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] ri INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT [Item No_], MAX([Posting Date]) AS maxDate 
      FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] 
      WHERE [Posting Date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2014-01-17 02:33:16.939') 
      GROUP BY [Item No_]] 
     ) itDat 
     ON ri.[Item No_] = itDat.[Item No_] and
        ri.[Posting Date] = itDat.maxDate
WHERE ri.[Quantity] > 0 
ORDER BY ri.[Location Code] DESC, ri.[Item No_] ASC, ri.[Posting Date] DESC;
```

An alternative way of writing this type of query is to use a `not exists` clause along with an index on `[Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry]([Item No_], [Posting Date])`:

```
SELECT ri.* 
FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] ri 
WHERE ri.[Quantity] > 0 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] ri2
                  WHERE ri2.[Item No_] = ri.[Item No_] AND
                        ri2.[Posting Date] > ri.[Posting Date]
                 )
ORDER BY ri.[Location Code] DESC, ri.[Item No_] ASC, ri.[Posting Date] DESC;
```

What this is saying is:  "Get me all the rows from that table with the too long and complicated name such that there are no other rows in the table with the same item number and a bigger posting date."

Comment: The second suggestion has the same results that I was getting; which is, that it will repeat rows with the same part number or even then same date. I am trying to get it to only bring up one instance per part number and date.

Comment: @BrandonShimek . . . Both queries should only be returning duplicate item numbers when there are duplicates on the maximum posting date for a given item.

Comment: I am trying to avoid duplicate entries for Item Numbers not trying to find only duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Does `[Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry]` have a primary key or unique index?  Without one, this might still give you duplicates but will still be an improvement:

```
SELECT ri.* 
FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] ri 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT [Item No_], MAX([Posting Date]) AS maxDate 
    FROM [Rigid Industries$Item Ledger Entry] 
    WHERE [Posting Date] <= CONVERT(datetime, '2014-01-17 02:33:16.939') 
    GROUP BY [Item No_] 
  ) itDat 
  ON ri.[Item No_] = itDat.[Item No_]
 AND ri.[Posting Date] = itDat.maxDate
WHERE ri.[Quantity] > 0 
ORDER BY ri.[Location Code] DESC, ri.[Item No_] ASC, ri.[Posting Date] DESC;
```

Comment: There is a column 'Entry No_' which has a unique value. The oldest date per part should logically be enough to avoid needing this but I am not opposed to incorporating its use for results.